# ARM assembly IDE for Linux (compiler, debugger, assembly view …)

Tags: linux, ide, arm, assembly

I recently began assembly development for a course I'm following and we are using [IAR Embedded Workbench IDE](http://www.iar.com/Products/IAR-Embedded-Workbench/) for which I did not find a Linux version.

What I actually need is a tool to compile and show the values in tooltips while debugging.

I wonder if there is anything that would do that job on Linux. I know and like Vim so writing the code in Vim and having a compiler/debugger plugin or something like that could suit me.

I'm doing some very basic ARM assembly. I do this for educational purposes and I won't run the program on anything else than the debugger itself.

I don't know which ARM version I am using, I guess you can assume the first one or some standard instructions that are available in all versions.

For now, I'm only using `LDR STR MOV` instructions and `DC32 DS32` variables. I guess that I will use more stuff as the course goes on.

This screenshot of IAR shows everything I need: code, disassembly and values. (just replace the C with assembly).

[image: IAR embedded workbench with debugger screenshot]

**Edit**

I've already used [Clewn](http://clewn.sourceforge.net/index.html) to debug some C++ code and it looks like gdb works also with assembly. If there is a full standalone IDE that has nothing to see with Vim it would be good for me, having a compiler that I can use with Clewn (gdb) is just as good.

Here is what Clewn looks like:

[image: Screenshot of Clewn]

Comment: What tasks are you looking for in this IDE? Usually the editor is considered an important part, but you state a preference for a standalone editor. Are you looking for an assembler? For integration between Vim (or other editor) and the assembler? Is this pure assembler or do you link with other code? What architectures do you need support for (ARMv8, Thumb, etc., and what executable format(s))? I presume you're looking for x86 tools?

Comment: As I said, I only do some very basic ARM assembly, I don't know the version and it doesn't matter, you can assume the first version I guess. I won't execute it on anything else than the debugger and I don't really care about the editor. What I need to do is be able to debug line per line the small standalone program that I will write seeing the values updating as the program goes.

Comment: @Johnride Please add the requirements specified in the  comment above to the question body.  You are likely to attract a higher quality answer if this information is consolidated.

Comment: @KellyThomas better now?

Comment: The screen shots and exptra copy don't help make this less broad because you are still not clear about your requirements. You want a compiler–no a plugin–no and IDE–with or without and editor–that may or may not do some things. See where this is going? You even state "without any particular goal". That's the problem with this question, without an exact problem you are trying to solve we can't give an exact answer. Without that scope this would turn into a "what is everybody's favorite way of doing X" question.

Comment: Well I can be more precise but I am afraid that the "ARM assembly debugging on Linux" scope is already very small that's why I am open to just about any solution. I can narrow it down to "Assembly debugging vim plugin" but that's not my goal here. I am looking for a recommendation about debugging ARM assembly on Linux : which tools to use. By "no particular goal" I mean that I am not building for a specific chip, I will change my words.

Answer (score 2):

This IDE is still a bit too young, but it certainly worth to be used! [SASM IDE](https://github.com/Dman95/SASM)

It has drawbacks:

1. when used with third-party libraries - it should be configured
2. when used with multiple-file projects - it should be configured
3. it has no per project configuration

Yet, it has its advantages:

1. syntax highlighting
2. one-button building
3. debugger
4. variable watcher

Comment: You just mention the drawbacks. So what are the advantages? How does it match the requirements (e.g. "compile and show the values in tooltips while debugging")? What makes it "certainly worth to be used"?

Comment: @Izzy it has GUI for both editor and debugger. And yeah, it has variable view window

Comment: That should be contained in your answer :) Maybe you [edit] it (and read our [hints for what we consider high quality answers](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) here – oh, better the other way around :)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For better or worse, I've had the summon-arm toolchain working (??) to various success levels in ubuntu  using eclipse and gdb.  The best instructions I've found are at http://vedder.se/2012/07/get-started-with-stm32f4-on-ubuntu-linux/

FWIW, I don't particularly care for Eclipse because of the Java bloated feeling.